# Hide rows based on specific text in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble in my vba function that uses a matrix to hide rows where there is a "." or "x" in two specific columns. It works with just one column, but I am not sure how to check for two columns. I think I have to combine these two loops into one loop but do not know how.

```
 ' hide rows when "x" or "." is in a specific column 
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range(TRange & LastRow)
    If c.Value = "." Or c.Value = "x" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

' hide rows when "x" or "." is in a specific column 
On Error Resume Next
For Each d In Range(FRange & LastRow)
    If d.Value <> "x" Then
        d.Value = "." Or d.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

The above is just part of the code - let me know if you need the rest of the code to help me.

Comment: Did you consider using `.Autofilter`? It serves the same purpose - to show only those rows that meet the requirement.

Comment: No - is that part of VBA? - it has to ork within VBA, hence I am combining it with other functions...

Comment: If you attach a simple picture illustrating your table (with dummy data, if it is confidential), I might come up with something, it is hard to provide solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using your method:

Here I assumed that `TRange` and `FRange` stand for columns T and F respectively.

```
Dim MySheet As Worksheet, i As Integer
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")
For i = Range(TRange & LastRow).Cells(1,1).Row To LastRow
    If MySheet.Cells(i,6) = "x" _
        or MySheet.Cells(i,6) = "." _
        or MySheet.Cells(i,20) = "x" _
        or MySheet.Cells(i,6) = "." _
        Then MySheet.Rows(i).Hidden = True
Next
```

I will post other solutions after you update your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

AntiDrondert suggested the simplest and most efficient solution: `.Autofilter`

You didn't provide all the specific details to your issue but if the working sheet is 1, and you need to hide "." or "x" in columns A and and B of the UsedRange, try this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideDotsAndXs()
    Const COL1 = 1  'Column A
    Const COL2 = 2  'Column B
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range

    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ur = ws.UsedRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ur
        ur.AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=COL1, Criteria1:="<>.", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>x"
        .AutoFilter Field:=COL2, Criteria1:="<>.", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>x"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Try to avoid the use of `On Error Resume Next`; it can often be replaced by `If Not IsError(...`